# Implementing Okasaki's bootstrapped heaps in OCaml, why doesn't it compile?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, functor

(A minimal non-compiling example can be found at https://gist.github.com/4044467, see more background below.)

I am trying to implement *Bootstrapped Heaps* introduced in Chapter 10 of Okasaki's *Purely Functional Data Structure*. The following is a simplified version of my non-compiling code.

We're to implement a heap with following signature:

```
module type ORDERED =
sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end

module type HEAP =
sig
  module Elem : ORDERED

  type heap

  val empty : heap
  val insert : Elem.t -> heap -> heap
  val find_min : heap -> Elem.t
  val delete_min : heap -> heap
end
```

We say a data structure is **bootstrapped** when its implementation depends on another implementation of the same kind of data structure. So we have a heap like this (the actual implementation is not important):

```
module SomeHeap (Element : ORDERED) : (HEAP with module Elem = Element) =
struct
  module Elem = Element

  type heap

  let empty = failwith "skipped"
  let insert = failwith "skipped"
  let find_min = failwith "skipped"
  let delete_min = failwith "skipped"
end
```

Then, the bootstrapped heap we're going to implement, which can depend on any heap implementation, is supposed to have the following signature:

```
module BootstrappedHeap
  (MakeH : functor (Element : ORDERED) -> HEAP with module Elem = Element)
  (Element : ORDERED) : (HEAP with module Elem = Element)
```

So we can use it like this:

```
module StringHeap = BootstrappedHeap(SomeHeap)(String)
```

The implementation of BootstrappedHeap, according to Okasaki, is like this:

```
module BootstrappedHeap
  (MakeH : functor (Element : ORDERED) -> HEAP with module Elem = Element)
  (Element : ORDERED) : (HEAP with module Elem = Element) =
struct
  module Elem = Element

  module rec BootstrappedElem :
  sig
    type t =
      | E
      | H of Elem.t * PrimH.heap
    val compare : t -> t -> int
  end =
  struct
    type t =
      | E
      | H of Elem.t * PrimH.heap
    let compare t1 t2 = match t1, t2 with
      | H (x, _), H (y, _) -> Elem.compare x y
      | _ -> failwith "unreachable"
  end
  and PrimH : (HEAP with module Elem = BootstrappedElem) =
    MakeH(BootstrappedElem)

  type heap

  let empty = failwith "not implemented"
  let insert = failwith "not implemented"
  let find_min = failwith "not implemented"
  let delete_min = failwith "not implemented"
end
```

But this is not compiling! The error message is:

```
File "ordered.ml", line 52, characters 15-55:
Error: In this `with' constraint, the new definition of Elem
       does not match its original definition in the constrained signature:
       Modules do not match:
         sig type t = BootstrappedElem.t end
       is not included in
         ORDERED
       The field `compare' is required but not provided
```

The line 52 is the line

```
and PrimH : (HEAP with module Elem = BootstrappedElem) =
```

I think `BootstrappedElem` did implement `ORDERED` as it has both `t` and `compare`, but I failed to see why the compiler fails to find the `compare` function.

Change the signature of BootstrappedElem to

```
module rec BootstrappedElem : ORDERED
```

will make it compiling but this will hide the type constructor `E` and `T` in `BootstrappedElem` to make it impossible to implement the later parts.

The whole non-compiling code can be downloaded at https://raw.github.com/gist/4044281/0ce0336c40b277e59cece43dbadb9b94ce6efdaf/ordered.ml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this might be a bug in the type-checker. I have reduced your code to the following example:

```
module type ORDERED =
sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
end


module type CARRY = sig
  module M : ORDERED
end

(* works *)
module HigherOrderFunctor
  (Make : functor (X : ORDERED) -> (CARRY with module M = X))
= struct
  module rec Base
    : (ORDERED with type t = string)
    = String
  and Other
    : (CARRY with module M = Base)
    = Make(Base)
end

(* does not work *)
module HigherOrderFunctor
  (Make : functor (X : ORDERED) -> (CARRY with module M = X))
= struct
  module rec Base
    : sig
      (* 'compare' seems dropped from this signature *)
      type t = string
      val compare : t -> t -> int
    end
    = String
  and Other
    : (CARRY with module M = (Base : sig type t = string val compare : t -> t -> int end))
    = Make(Base)
end
```

I don't understand why the first code works and the second (which seems equivalent) doesn't. I suggest you wait a bit to see if an expert comes with an explanation (Andreas?), then consider sending [a bug report](http://caml.inria.fr/mantis/view_all_bug_page.php).

In this case, a solution is to first bind the signature that seems mishandled:

```
(* works again *)
module HigherOrderFunctor
  (Make : functor (X : ORDERED) -> (CARRY with module M = X))
= struct
  (* bind the problematic signature first *)
  module type S = sig
    type t = string
    val compare : t -> t -> int
  end

  module rec Base : S = String
  and Other : (CARRY with module M = Base) = Make(Base)
end
```

However, that is not possible in your setting, because the signature of `BootstrappedElem` is mutually recursive with `BootstrappedHeap`.

A workaround is to avoid the apparently-delicate `with module ...` construct and replace it with a simple type equality `with type Elem.t = ...`:

```
module BootstrappedHeap
  (MakeH : functor (Element : ORDERED) -> HEAP with module Elem = Element)
  (Element : ORDERED) : (HEAP with module Elem = Element) =
struct
  module Elem = Element

  module rec BootstrappedElem :
  sig
    type t =
      | E
      | H of Elem.t * PrimH.heap
    val compare : t -> t -> int
  end =
  struct
    type t =
      | E
      | H of Elem.t * PrimH.heap
    let compare t1 t2 = match t1, t2 with
      | H (x, _), H (y, _) -> Elem.compare x y
      | _ -> failwith "unreachable"
  end
  and PrimH : (HEAP with type Elem.t = BootstrappedElem.t) =
    MakeH(BootstrappedElem)

  type heap

  let empty = failwith "not implemented"
  let insert = failwith "not implemented"
  let find_min = failwith "not implemented"
  let delete_min = failwith "not implemented"
end
```

You could also avoid the mutual recursion and define both `BootstrappedElem` and `BootstrappedHeap` in one recursive knot, by defining `BootstrappedElem` *inside* the recursive `BootstrappedHeap`.

```
module BootstrappedHeap
  (MakeH : functor (Element : ORDERED) -> HEAP with module Elem = Element)
  (Element : ORDERED) : (HEAP with module Elem = Element) =
struct
  module rec BootstrappedHeap : sig
    module Elem : sig
      type t = E | H of Element.t * BootstrappedHeap.heap
      val compare : t -> t -> int
    end        
    include (HEAP with module Elem := Elem)
  end = struct
    module Elem = struct
      type t = E | H of Element.t * BootstrappedHeap.heap
      let compare t1 t2 = match t1, t2 with
        | H (x, _), H (y, _) -> Element.compare x y
        | _ -> failwith "unreachable"
    end
    include (MakeH(Elem) : HEAP with module Elem := Elem)
  end

  module Elem = Element

  type heap

  let empty = failwith "not implemented"
  let insert = failwith "not implemented"
  let find_min = failwith "not implemented"
  let delete_min = failwith "not implemented"
end
```

This style corresponds naturally to your decision of embedding `Elem` in the `HEAP` signature and using `with module ...` for refinement. Another solution would have been to define `HEAP` as a functor returning a signature, used as `HEAP(Elem).S`, and I suppose a different recursive style could have been chosed. Not to say that this would have been better: I think the "abstract module" style is more convenient.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do think it seems very like a compiler bug. I'll report this bug if more people can confirm it.